# Whitelabel error page on the first server hit- Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

I am following the basic Spring Boot application steps to setup the basic Spring Boot app. Have created REST controller as required. After running the application, however, I get this text on localhost:8080- "Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, 
so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Thursday Nov 07 01:41:42 IST 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available "

Tried adding another callback method apart from the '/' mapping, but it gives the same error.

Controller code:

```
    @RestController
        public class TestController {
        @RequestMapping(value = "/")
         public String home() {
          return "Spring boot is working!";
         }

         @RequestMapping("/testing")
         public String testing() {
          return "Spring boot is working!";
         }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting in below class level annotation in your main class:
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {(name of your controller package)}

Answer (score 1):

Explicit @ComponentScan doesn't require if your Application class annotated with @SpringBootApplication is in root and others are sub packages of it.